# How to get products with a specific attribute value

Tags: product, attributes, product-attribute, filter, attribute-set

How can I get the products with a attribute (attribute name is "use_state") value of "new"? I added an attribute called "use_state" and an attribute set with that attribute. Then I created some products that have this attribute set and assigned value "new" to these products' "use_state" attribute. For the world, I cannot anyhow get these products in my block, in order to be able to display them. I tried these approaches and each one was just giving me some useless information that I don't even understand, instead of the concrete products information, that I actually expect from them. I tried this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') -> getCollection(); 
$collection -> addAttributeToSelect(array('name'));
$collection -> addFieldToFilter("use_state", "new");

print "DEV: <pre>"; print_r($collection); print "</pre>";

$_products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'))
->addAttributeToFilter('use_state', 'new')
->load();

echo "DEV: <pre>"; print_r($_products); echo "</pre>";
```

Not giving me any products, just some info that I don't even understand. Can you help me see what's wrong here?

I have just found out that this line might be the culprit:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('use_state', 'new')
```

, and this is because 'new' is not the value to filter by, but another, coded value, which is in my case, 234. I don't know how to translate 'new' to 234 though.

Comment: I have just found out that this line might be the culprit:
->addAttributeToFilter('use_state', 'new')
, and this is because 'new' is not the value to filter by, but another, coded value, which is in my case, 234. I don't know how to translate 'new' to 234 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found out that this line is the culprit:

`->addAttributeToFilter('use_state', 'new')`

, and this is because 'new' is not the value to filter by, but another, coded value, which is in my case, 234. I don't know how to translate 'new' to 234 though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');  
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
```

//products whose price is 100

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'price','100'),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.3.4 you can use this:

```php
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class SomeClass
{

    protected $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    public function something() 
    {
        $productCollection = $this->collectionFactory
                    ->create()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'attribute_value');
    }
}
```

`attribute_code` you can find in the `eav_attribute` table.